# Pre-fix the foreign table with the schema - postgres_pwd

Tags: postgresql

If I follow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#postgresql-commondbatasks-fdw, how can I pre-fix the tables with the schema I am retrieving tables from, e.g.

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA lands 
LIMIT TO (land, land2) 
FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO public;
```

The created tables are named land and land2. Is it possible to prefix land and land2 with 'lands', e.g. 'lands_land' and 'lands_land2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `psql` and recent PostgreSQL versions, you could simply run (after the `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`):

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER FOREIGN TABLE public.%I RENAME TO %I;',
          relname,
          'lands_' || relname
       )
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'f'  -- foreign table
  AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace \gexec
```

The `\gexec` will interpret each result row as an SQL stateent and execute it.

Another option that I'd like better is to keep the original names, but use a different schema for the foreign tables:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA lands 
LIMIT TO (land, land2) 
FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO lands;
```

Then all foreign tables will be in a schema `lands`, and you have the same effect in a more natural fashion. You can adjust `search_path` to include the `lands` schema.

Comment: Thank you for teachning the best practices! I opted for the 2nd option.